# C# file creation is not working after setup file is created

Tags: c#, json, wpf, setup-project

I have an app which is creating .json file. User enters required data and then app creates .json file inside bin folder:

```
File.WriteAllText("dbconfig.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbconfig, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

Next time I start app the code reads bin folder using Environment.CurrentDirectory an searches for a .json file:

```
File.Exists($"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\dbconfig.json"
```

I am using this so that user shouldn't need to enter the same data everytime he starts an app, only once for the first time. While debugging everything is working fine. The problem is that after I've created setup file and install an application, after I enter required data to be saved to .json and press OK the application crashes.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem can be? Maybe something is wrong with file creation? I've never done such thing before so there is great possibility that I'm missing something in my code.

Comment: In which directory do you install / start the app?  Usually non-admin users to not have write permissions to the `Program Files` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Almost impossible to say without more information like what is the exception? Is the error in the file create or json serialization.

Off the top of my head it could be dependent on where you install application. i.e. is it under a protected folder where you may need elevated privileges.

Looking at your filename looks like you want to store some user data, ideally those files should be stored in the users profile or all users profile. Try something like

```
        // create a folder to store user data under c:\users\username\appdata\local
        var appDataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "myapp");
        if (!Directory.Exists(appDataPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(appDataPath);
        }

        //Write json to file
        var jsonFile = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "dbconfig.json");
        File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbconfig, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));

        //ToRead
        if (File.Exists(jsonFile))
        {
            var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
            .....
        }
```